# zeromq multithreading, How threads receiving messages from REP socket?

Tags: multithreading, sockets, zeromq

MTthreading, threads in worker routine, recieve message through REP socket.Isnt REP socket supposed to send messages in zeroMQ? I am new at zeromq

Comment: With due respect, @monsterrrrr, as posted in your other question, would you kindly accept the StackOverflow netiquette to post a sign of both your own efforts and code, that you ask the community here to sponsor you on problem resolution? Saying "I am new at XYZ" is usually a poor excuse for not being fair to others. Show your design, show your tests / errors / exceptions and show, what have you tried so far to make your code work. Life-long learning is a way to achieve results. Demonstrate your fair steps in this direction and you will get a lot of help from people around here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### ZeroMQ is a great tool

getting familiar with ZeroMQ means, there is to be some learning path to get it's great power under one's control.

Would be great to spend a few days / weeks on Pieter Hintjens book "**Code Connected, Volume 1**" ( available in PDF )

There you will get grounds for your further use of ZeroMQ.

### Isn't REP socket supposed to... ?

There is an important abstraction. A ZMQ socket is not "just a socket", the ZeroMQ way is to formalise both the device per-se ( `.socket()` object instance ) and also some formal communication pattern ( an "archetype" -- PUB, REP, PAIR et al )

As among the people on the phone line ( 1+1 or 1+N in a conference call ), there is some habit, some generally accepted manner, how they listen and how they speak to their counterparty(-ies).

This way you always have feasible and non-feasible combinations -- `PUB` can speak whatever & whenever it wants, while all `SUB`-s listen and listen and listen

This way imagine your **`REP`** to be supposed to be "on a phone call" with **`REQ`** in a `REQ`/`REP` **pattern**, where a request arrives during their connection from <*REQ*> side ( it is your <*REP*> side is ***supposed*** to be listening ) and upon such event, your <*REP*> side is expected to respond via it's `REP .socket()` instance back to the requesting side ( whereas your <*REP*> side is ***supposed*** to be talking ).

### So, it is supposed to ...

... receive messages & send messages ( in accord with the formal communication pattern ).

### The best next step

IMHO if you are serious about professional messaging, get the great book and source both the elementary setups knowledge, a bit more complex multi-socket messaging layer designs with soft signalling & also the further thoughts about the great powers of concurrent, heterogenous, distributed processing to advance your learning curve.

ZeroMQ is a great way to do this, not just for the messaging layer itself.
[image: multi-socket messaging layer with soft signalling]